# Permissions error when trying to attach file in Android e-mail

Tags: android, email, android-intent, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin.Android and I have a log file that I create and add to as any exceptions or messages are logged. A very simply logger, just writing to a text file.  When someone submits a bug report I want to attach the log.txt file to the e-mail.  This fails due to a permissions error (I don't have the specifics) but it's related to the folder I'm storing the log file in.  I'm using the following code which will show you where I store the log.txt file.

```
    public readonly static string BaseDir = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
    public readonly static string LogFilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(BaseDir, "log.txt");
```

Here is the code I use to attach the log.txt file which does not work:

```
Java.IO.File file = new Java.IO.File(Utils.LogFilename);
intent.PutExtra(Intent.ExtraStream, Android.Net.Uri.FromFile(file));
```

Where is the correct place to store a file on any Android device (SD card or not) to allow the attachment to work with e-mail?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);` will give you the apps private directory, which resolves to `/data/data/<your app namespace>/files` and is only readable by your app in particular.

What you probably want is to use `Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory` which gives you the path to the external storage, this could be the SDcard. This is device dependent. In there you could make a folder for your app in particular and store files in it, which in turn you could pass to the E-mail app.

Comment: Thanks, need to add permission to write_external_storage as well.